# How to set id of next element into href attribute of link using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes, href

I have to assign to many html `href` attributes (a tag) the value of their respective id immediately following.
With my code, I just get a only value (the first).
Thanks so much.
Juri

```js
$(".anchor").attr("href","#"+($(".anchor").closest("div").next("div").attr("id")));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <a class="anchor">Get anchor 1</a>
</div>
<div id="link1">
    <p>A paragraph</p>
</div>
<div>
    <a class="anchor">Get anchor 2</a>
</div>
<div id="link2">
    <p>Another paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Did your problem solved?

Comment: @Mohammad yes, thank you so much, you all are the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) with function in second parameter, iterate selected elements and change attribute of its. Also use `.parent()` instead of `.closest("div")`

```js
$(".anchor").attr("href", function(){
    return "#"+$(this).parent().next("div").attr("id");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <a class="anchor">Get anchor 1</a>
</div>
<div id="link1">
    <p>A paragraph</p>
</div>
<div>
    <a class="anchor">Get anchor 2</a>
</div>
<div id="link2">
    <p>Another paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the instance of the selected element. Can use [`attr(attrName, function)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) to do it

```
$(".anchor").attr("href",function(){
    return '#' + $(this).closest("div").next("div").attr("id");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate a loop through all the a tag having class anchor and use `$(this).parent("div").next("div").attr("id"))` selector to get the link for the a tag.

Please check below snippet.

```js
$(".anchor").each(function(){
  $(this).attr("href","#"+($(this).parent("div").next("div").attr("id")));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div><a class="anchor">Get anchor 1</a>
</div>
<div id="link1">
<p>A paragraph</p>
</div>

<div><a class="anchor">Get anchor 2</a>
</div>
<div id="link2">
<p>Another paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery `each` OR any loop like `for`, `while` etc to iterate on all .anchor elements.